# git filter-branch retains too much history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I am working on splitting a quite large monorepo up into multiple repos, per application. The monorepo has a folder structure like this:

```
|- a
|  |- application1
|  |- application2
|- b
|  |- application3
|  |- application4
|- c
|  |- application5
```

If I want to migrate application1, I run the following commands:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --subdirectory-filter "a/application1" -- --all
git reset --hard
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

This has been working for multiple applications, but now I have gotten into a problem: One of the migrated applications has a huge git history, close to the size of the monorepo itself. When inspecting the history, I find that it retains most of the history of the mono-repo, including commits belonging to other applications.

When browsing through the history, the latest commits look good, they are all related to the migrated application. The turning point seems to be a commit, where the application in question was moved from a folder to another (so lets assume that application1 was at one point `git mv`-ed from folder b to folder a). The history prior to this move seems to contain all history for the entire monorepo.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: It seems that application1 was first `git mv`-ed from `b` to `a`, then reverted, then moved to `a` again. Not sure if this is what makes git confused..

Comment: Your subdirectory filter tells Git: *for each commit, remove all but `a/application1` files*. Any commits that have files in `b/application1` are uninteresting here. There's no really good way to keep the `b/application1` files with a `--subdirectory-filter`; you need a more complex filter.

Comment: Remember that except for the fact that each commit records its parents, all the commits are independent snapshots. Dropping (from the copying process) all the `b/...` ones still leaves you with (copies of) the `a/...` ones from before the name change plus the `a/...` ones from after the name change. It just removes all the in-between ones.

Comment: Also, in my migrated git history, the `git mv` appears to create files, rather than move, so the history prior to the move is not available when I look at file history. Kind of makes sense, since the old folder doesn't have meaning in my new repo. A solution then _might_ be to remove all git history prior to the move, but then again it would be nice to keep the changes from before as well.

Comment: @torek if I create a filter that covers both a/application1 and b/application1 (which only exists in the git history), could that work?

Comment: It could, but note that it's not all that easy to write the right filter. An index filter that uses `git rm -r --cached` of everything that's not `a/application1` or `b/application1` would do it, but it's tricky to get that list of "everything".

Comment: Ok, so to save myself some headache, perhaps I should just find a way to delete all git history from before the move of the application in question? There is still a few years of history, so probably acceptable.

Comment: That's possible, and perhaps easier, using `git replace --graft` to cut the history off. The filter-branch command obeys replacements by default.